# log4j and java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Layout

Tags: java, log4j, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to get a piece of code working with log4j.  If I run it via junit tests (ant task), I am getting proper log outputs and all is fine.  If I run the code from the command line, I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Layout
        at uk.co.bytemark.flexnbd.Main.main(Main.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Layout
```

I tried the two following classpaths but neither helped.  The error remains.

```
  export CLASSPATH=/home/yann/java/apache-log4j-1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar 
  export CLASSPATH=/home/yann/java/apache-log4j-1.2.16/
```

Even with this

```
$ java -cp /home/yann/java/apache-log4j-1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar -jar ./dist/lib/flexnbd-`date +%Y%m%d`.jar server ::1 12345 fileSystem
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Layout
        at uk.co.bytemark.flexnbd.Main.main(Main.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Layout
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        ... 1 more
$ ls -ld /home/yann/java/apache-log4j-1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar
476K -rw-r--r-- 1 yann yann 471K Mar 31 05:16 /home/yann/java/apache-log4j-1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think you overwrite the classpath. try this, but not sure, so this is not a pretty answer:

export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/home/yann/java/apache-log4j-1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/home/yann/java/apache-log4j-1.2.16/

Comment: Ok, can you write the command line please ?

Comment: yes, thx. hope my answer can help you

Comment: did you check the content of your jar ? Maybe your download went wrong and the class is missing. try unzipping it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the problem.  If you use -jar, your CLASSPATH is ignored.  A better command line is thus:

```
java -cp dist/lib/flexnbd-20100716.jar:/home/yann/java/apache-log4j-1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar uk.co.bytemark.flexnbd.Main [...]
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Cool :), finally I was almost right, but I just forget to include dist/lib/flexnbd-20100716.jar in the classpath. I delete my answer, since it's not usefull
you can accept your answer :)